# How to extract numeric value instead of text from GuiTableControl?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I use Excel VBA to automate tasks in SAP.

Many times when dealing with `GuiTableControl`​ the numbers and dates are formatted as text, not values. That causes problems when users have different settings (commas and points as decimal separator, for example).

Is there a function like getcellvalue in `GuiGridView`?

A workaround would be to access the User Profile in System/User Profile/Own Data/Defaults to get the default format for the current user, and create a function to convert the text to a value depending on the default format.

[image: Example of User Profile in SAP]

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a variable and using the "text" property of the field from the script. For example:

```
myVariable = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabs_blah_blah").Text
```

Then use the variable in Excel to populate the formulae to convert in the correct way.

Comment: Yes, of course, but if you don't know the system of the user you can't know how to convert the text to a value.   ( whether if points or commas are used as the decimal separator for example)